# AWS EC2: Baseline of 3 IOPS per GiB with a minimum of 100 IOPS

Tags: amazon-ec2, volume

I seem to remember the policy was `Baseline of 3 IOPS per GiB`. If I have a volumn of 8GB, I get 24 IOPS. Now with the `a minimum of 100 IOPS`, do I get at least 100 IOPS no matter how small my volumn is?

Comment: maybe a better fit for server fault? it sounds like it to me... amazon has customer service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at 33.33 GiB and below, an EBS SSD (gp2) volume will have 100 IOPS. This is spelled out clearly in [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html).

Comment: Oh see the doc: `General Purpose SSD (gp2) volumes offer cost-effective storage that is ideal for a broad range of workloads. These volumes deliver single-digit millisecond latencies and the ability to burst to 3,000 IOPS for extended periods of time. Between a minimum of 100 IOPS (at 33.33 GiB and below) and a maximum of 10,000 IOPS (at 3,334 GiB and above), baseline performance scales linearly at 3 IOPS per GiB of volume size. A gp2 volume can range in size from 1 GiB to 16 TiB.` I think AWS added this minimum recently.